# Update modules manually on Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In recent days, it has become impossible to update the modules. I receive an error such as "*this is not a valid module name*".

Is it possible to manually update the modules by retrieving the latest files from Github? I tried to replace the files with those of the latest version but, it doesn't change anything at all.

I precise that I try to update official modules that are pre-installed in Prestashop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

Grab the moduble from GitHub, wrap the whole module (the ps_xxxxxx directory) in a zip file then install the module from the admin interface.

Don't replace the files manually by using  the filesystem (or at least try not to).
If you replace the modules in the modules directory you won't trigger the module "install" method, so if the new version needs some initialization it won't work properly.

EDIT:
Some modules have dependencies, for example ps_facetedsearch will require you to install composer and run 'composer install --no-dev' before you can pack it into a zip.

Alternatively you can get a json list of native prestashop modules here (replace [VERSION] with the version of prestashop you want, ex 1.7.6.4) :

https://api-addons.prestashop.com/?format=json&iso_lang=en&iso_code=all&version=[VERSION]&method=listing&action=native

Then you can download the module with its id with this URL (replace [VERSION] and [MODULE_ID] :

https://api-addons.prestashop.com/?format=json&iso_lang=en&iso_code=EN&version=[VERSION]&method=module&id_module=[MODULE_ID]

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I also add for the people having the same problem: from Github, the archive has a suffix "-master", remove it so the directory inside the archive is named "ps_xxxx" only and not "ps_xxxx-master".

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful!